# .Net Core Web API manually validate Azure AD access Token and get user details

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to validate an Azure AD token(loginResponse.idToken) generated by an React app after Azure AD Validating the user.

In my Web API backend I need to manually validate the token in one of my Web API's and get the user details from the access token. And then send a new JWT token create by the .Net core app.

I tried to validate the Azure AD token, but failed. I tried based on the example [on validating the token](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-azure-ad-token-using-console-application/), but failed.

It returns the error "Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]".

Can anyone help me to validate the token and get the user details form the token.

Comment: How do you set up the `scope`?

Comment: Parse your access token and provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the `scope`. You may have set the wrong `scope`.

I answered similar questions before, first you need to **expose** the api of the back-end application in Azure. Then you need to set the `scope` to: `{your api application client id}/{scope name}`.

Please be careful not to add the `api://` prefix.

Comment: can you explain how we can do this? any link to documentation would be useful. in my case I'm generating a token on nuxt and sent it to .net webapi, when doing the tokenHandler.ValidateToken I got the exception mentioned by Thanushka